# What is this IC on the PCB? Top marking H09

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

[image]

What is this IC on the PCB? Top marking H09.

Comment: What's around it, where does it connect to?

Comment: Please add a description of what the circuit does, and show a photo of the surrounding circuitry as per the [Component Identification Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6710/component-identification-question-guidelines).

Answer (score 6):

Could be an [AD8014](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8014.pdf) high performance current-feedback amplifier.

[image]

Comment: LCSC has a [picture](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Operational-Amplifier_Analog-Devices-AD8014ARTZ-REEL7_C578596.html) that shows the same marking style. +1.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly Ricoh RP111N091B.

SOT-23-5    Linear voltage regulator IC
LDO, 0.9V±0.8%, 500mA, +CE

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can also be some LDO from Torex Semiconductor
[image]
https://smd.yooneed.one/code4830.html